# ProxyPass - Invalid URL

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am creating a simple proxy pass in Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6 but that's not working and throwing error. I would be thankful if someone can please help:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass  /  https://ecuo-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com/
ProxyPassReverse  /  https://ecuo-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com/
```

Now when I call it as http://MyHostName/finApInvQuickInvoicesModel/InvoiceInterfaceService?wsdl it throws following error:

```
Invalid URL  The requested URL
"http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/finApInvQuickInvoicesModel/InvoiceInterfaceService?", is invalid. Reference #9.76fd241.1465372087.68aff0d
```

Whereas https://ecuo-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com/finApInvQuickInvoicesModel/InvoiceInterfaceService?wsdl works very fine.

Can you please help me fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

At a *guess*, you might need to turn on `ProxyPreserveHost`. ([Docs are here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost))

Without it, the proxy-request that Apache is making to `ecuo-test.fin.us2.oraclecloud.com` will have a `Host` header of `MyHostName`, and I *guess* that the error is trying to indicate that the eventual host doesn't recognise that host name.